# How to get all the applications that offer an Intent with a specific pattern?

Tags: android, android-intent, pattern-matching

Actually I have this code to get all the apps that offer an Intent with a full specified action name.

```
public List<ResolveInfo> getAll() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.intent.A");

    final PackageManager mgr = mContext.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> list = mgr.queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

    return list;
}
```

How can I get all the apps that offer custom Intents with an action name specified by a pattern?

I would specify only the first part of the action name, something like **com.example.intent.***, and then get all the app that respond to the intent:

- *com.example.intent.A*
- *com.example.intent.BBBB*
- *com.example.intent.CCC*
- ... etc.

It's important to note that this application doesn't know the full names of the intent.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @CommonsWare on this. It is not possible. Android supports Intent resolution by exact matching of ACTION strings, so it doesn't need to support the functionality that you want.

Theoretically you could request a list of all installed packages from the `PackageManager` and then scan through all the activities in each package looking at the `ActivityInfo` objects and the associated Intent filters. Unfortunately, there is no way to get the Intent filters associated with an activity (this was conveniently left out of the `ActivityInfo` class).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think that exists a way to do that using some other field of the intent instead of the action name (for example a custom category that all the intents share)?

Comment: No. that's not possible. To get a match, the ACTION must match. If you don't know the ACTION, no other fields will help with a match. What is it that you are trying to do?